# getting error while using livybatch operator in Airflow , DAG getting crashed

Tags: livy, airflow

Can someone help me on this while using livybatchoperator in Airflow , below is my code  ...
apart from that what's other way to run spark job in airflow except spark operator, spark is installed on different machine in my case.

I'm getting this error : `Getting Error in Airflow UI - "No module named 'airflow_livy'"` .

````
```    
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from airflow_livy.batch import LivyBatchOperator
    from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
    from airflow.models import DAG
    
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start-date': datetime(2020, 8, 4),
        'retires': 0,
        'catchup': False,
        'retry-delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    }
    
    
    
    
    dag_config: DAG = DAG(
        'Airflow7', description='Hello world example', schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
        start_date=datetime(2020, 8, 4), catchup=False)
    
    
    
    
    livy_Operator_SubmitTask = LivyBatchOperator(
        task_id='spark-submit_job_livy',
        class_name='Class name ',
        file='File path of my jar',
        arguments=['Test'],
        verify_in='spark',
        dag=dag_config
    )
    
    
    
    livy_Operator_SubmitTask```
````

Comment: Getting Error in Airflow UI  - "No module named 'airflow_livy'" .

Answer (score 0):

Try importing this namespace instead:

```
from airflow.providers.apache.livy.operators.livy import LivyOperator
```

Found from:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/apache/livy/example_dags/example_livy.py